# Retrieve Id of the sub item anchor tag in Angular Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have anchor tags in the HTML as below. Just I am using Angular Material List -> mat-list and mat-list-item here.

```html
<a id="userMgmtId" click)="NavLink($event)" mat-list-item matTooltip="User Management">
  <mat-icon>user_panel_settings</mat-icon>
  <span>User Management</span>
  <mat-list class="header-anchor-tag" [hidden]="!isSubNavVisible" style="position: absolute; top: 35px; z-index: 10; flex-direction: column;">
    <a id="userListId" mat-list-item class="mat-list-item-content" [routerLink]="['/user-list']" routerLinkActive="active">User List</a>
    <a id="userGroupsId" mat-list-item class="mat-list-item-content" [routerLink]="['/user-groups']" routerLinkActive="active">User Groups</a>
    <a id="allUsersId" mat-list-item class="mat-list-item-content" [routerLink]="['/all-users']" routerLinkActive="active">All Users</a>
  </mat-list>
</a>
```

This is just like displaying a new menu item, User Management and under that we have 3 sub items list.

With this code, I want to retrieve the Id of the clicked Sub Item Anchor tag so that I will work on other things..

The code of Typescript Angular is here..

```
NavLink(event: Event): void {
  if (isAdmin) {
    // ...
  } else {
    // ...
  }
  
  this.isHandheld ?? this.Nav.toggle();
}
```

What I am trying is I want to know whether any sub list is clicked or not. When it is clicked, then I should not hide the sub list items. If the user clicks other Header Items, then this Sub list items, should close.

I tried the below code, but I am unable to retrieve the clicked link id..

```
onClick(event: Event) {
  // Get a reference to the element that was clicked.
  const clickedElement = event.target as HTMLElement;

  // Get the closest ancestor element that has an ID attribute.
  const subListItemAnchorTag = clickedElement.closest('[id]');

  // If the sub list item anchor tag is not null, then get its ID.
  if (subListItemAnchorTag) {
    // The sub list item anchor tag has an ID.
    const subListItemAnchorId = subListItemAnchorTag.getAttribute('id');

    // Do something with the sub list item anchor ID.
    console.log(subListItemAnchorId);
  } else {
    // The sub list item anchor tag does not have an ID.
    console.log('The sub list item anchor tag does not have an ID.');
  }
}
```

But this code is not working. Don't know why.